# How to release BB10 app for beta testing

Tags: blackberry-10

I want to know how to release blackberry 10 apps to the client for beta testing. as in bb7 we were uploading web folder on the project server and give path to jad file to the client to download app to their phone. What would be the way for bb10

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy a release build, signed, to the BlackBerry World, just don't send it for review. It will be accessible to all people in your account's sandbox, and only to them.

Answer (score 0):

We need to release our .bar file and should ask client or QA person to install it using "Side loading"

Answer (score 0):

There's virtually no difference in building release for submitting to App World or for client testing from IDE/developer perspective. Just use "Export" menu option in the project menu, then follow instructions to build a release and send a resulting bar-file over to a client.

In order to deploy it on a device for testing, you need to do side-loading using DDPD software which could be found here - http://ddpb.dauden.vn/